# Custom ExpressionBuilder in the middle of strings

Tags: c#, asp.net, globalization

I've created a custom `ExpressionBuilder` to accompany a custom resource factory, in an attempt to move resources from files to an external database. Everything is working fine, however when attempting to evaluate an expression I run into the following problem. (Assuming the resource `HelloWorld` evaluates to `Hello World`)

### Scenario 1

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources: HelloWorld %>" />
```

- Expected: `Hello World`
- Actual: `Hello World`

### Scenario 2

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" Text="Say <%$ Resources: HelloWorld %>" />
```

- Expected: `Say Hello World`
- Actual: `Say <%$ Resources: HelloWorld %>`

Comment: I think that may just be what asp.net does. I've seen the same thing attempted & failing with data binding expressions.

Comment: @SimonHalsey Hmm, odd; the default resource expression builder evaluates this without any problems?

Comment: I tried, couldnt find a way